# post-receive on a mirrored git repo?

Tags: git

I have a git repo that mirrored from remote server. The remote server doesn't support post commit email notification and I don't have access to it either. Yet, I am hoping to have a way to detect new commits on this mirrored copy and send out corresponding email notification. Is it possible at all?

thanks

Oliver

Answer (score 1):

yes. You can do an update hook and run a script every time there is an update. The 3 arguments that git passes to that hook are branch name, old hash and new hash. You can take this range and do an email per commit or just one for all the commits.

However, since this is a secondary repo, you will need to get a scheduled job to update it from the main one.

Comment: I think I have tried both: post-receive hook and update hook. Neither seems to be working. The scheduled cron job does "git fetch -q" to pull changes from remote.

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting errors? can you at least echo out the params? `echo $1 $2 $3`

Comment: It may be the wrong hook. The update hook is invoked when a repo is pushed to.

Comment: To fix this, clone a bare repo, stick the hook in there. Automate pushing from your repo to it. The hook that you want is the one that acts on the /remote/ repository. This should do it.

Comment: I can't do push from the remote repo, I am merely mirroring it. Unless the "update" hook can be invoked when "git fetch" is run ...

Answer (score 0):

As part of [gitmirror](https://github.com/dustin/gitmirror), I made myself a `post-fetch` hook to allow me receive a post from github (for example), do a fetch, and then do doc builds and such.

I also use this without github where I have a little bit of curl to notify the remote end that changes have come in.  If you can get an http connection from the source to the dest, you can pretty much do whatever you want with these tools.

I move tons of commits over a lot of projects and proxy those down a kind of tree config on these.

Comment: I will give it a shot later, and see how it is. Thanks for the info.